# Django REST - AssertionError: `fields` must be a list or tuple

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

When querying Django via REST using the Django REST framework I get the error,

```
  File "/folder/pythonenv/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 241, in get_fields
    assert isinstance(self.opts.fields, (list, tuple)), '`fields` must be a list or tuple'
AssertionError: `fields` must be a list or tuple
```

My settings are....

**settings.py**

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
        'south',  # Database migration helpers:
        'crispy_forms',  # Form layouts
        'rest_framework',
    )

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
                'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
                    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
                )
    }
```

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from quickstart.serializers import from quickstart.serializers import TicketInputSerializer
from models import Abc

class TicketInputViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Abc.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TicketInputSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'ticket', views.TicketViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^test', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

)
```

**Serializers**

```
from models import Abc
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers

class TicketInputSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Abc
        fields = ('test',)
```

**Models**

```
from django.db import models

class Abc(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use a tuple or list for `fields`, to represent a tuple with single item you need to use a trailing comma:

```
fields = ('test', )
```

Without a comma `fields = ('test')` is actually equivalent to `fields = 'test'`.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
>   items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
>   tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
>   one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
>   sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but
>   effective.

Comment: @felix001 I'd guarantee that this is the right answer to your question.  Double check your serializer `fields` settings in all your serializers and make sure you've restarted the devserver after doing so.

Answer (score 8):

`('test')` is not a tuple, it is the [same](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) value as simply `'test'`.

You should add a trailing comma to create a singleton tuple:

```
fields = ('test',)
```

Or you can use a list and don't bother about the commas:

```
fields = ['test']
```